# How Can I get HTML From Flutter Quill(flutter_quill) with underline

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert Quill Delta to HTML. So I can upload it to my server. anyone help me how can I get Html from Quill

I have used delta to markdown and then markdown to html. but I have underline so it not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I have fixed this issue. as per your Delta to Markdown and markdown to html not working because markdown not supported underline yet. so you have to convert delta to html directly.

You can use this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/delta_to_html)

then try below code. This bill give you html output.

```
List deltaJson = quillController.document.toDelta().toJson();

print(DeltaToHTML.encodeJson(deltaJson));
```